# A previously folded template instantiates in different class when unfolded than instantiating original version

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

I collect non instantiated templates into a wrapper tuple class.

Later in the code I instantiate every template in the wrapper with same parameter.

And later, I want to check if one of the templates was included in the tuple using the same parameters that the tuple used at point of instantiation.

However, they never match. I wrote below a simplified example that will print the typeid name of the item in the tuple and the original item when not the same.

```
#include<tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<template<typename TIME> class... Ms>
struct models_tuple {
    template<typename T>
    using type=std::tuple<Ms<T>...>;
};

template<class TIME>
struct model_a{};
using mt1=models_tuple<model_a>;

int main(){
if (std::is_same<mt1::type<float>, model_a<float>>::value) {
     std::cout << "first item in tuple model instantiated in float is the original model instantiated in float" << std::endl;
} else {
     std::cout << "first item in tuple model instantiated in float is NOT the original" << std::endl;
     std::cout << "model: " << typeid(model_a<float>()).name() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "model tuple: " << typeid(mt1::type<float>()).name() << std::endl;
     auto m1 = std::get<0>(mt1::type<float>());
     std::cout << "first model in tuple: " << typeid(m1).name() << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The result from running it is the following.

```
first item in tuple model instantiated in float is NOT the original 
model: F7model_aIfEvE
model tuple: FNSt3__15tupleIJ7model_aIfEEEEvE
first model in tuple: 7model_aIfE
```

I see this difference of a "F" prefix and an "fE" suffix in the mangled version of the typename, but not figuring out why they are there.

Comment: `is_same<mt1::type<float>, std::tuple<model_a<float>>>`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I messed up when simplifying the example. This one was failing just because passing a tuple as you mention. Going back to the dive deep into the original code to find if I can extract a small example.